# É possível manipular erros do PHP via código?

Tags: php, exceção, recuperação-de-erros

Como todos sabem, o PHP retorna os erros de sintaxe em tempo de execução no navegador, como erros fatais e exceptions.

É possível tratar esses erros via código de forma que eu possa salvar no banco de dados em uma tabela de logs de erros?

A necessidade disso é porque utilizo um arquivo PHP para receber POST externo e caso eu errar a sintaxe ou lançar alguma exception nesse arquivo, não saberei como e onde ocorreu.

Answer (score 11):

Note que dependendo do erro, a execução do script será interrompida. Se em algum momento deu DB parou e gerou um erro, você não vai poder gerar o LOG, por isso, geralmente os LOGs são gravados em um TXT simples, com data-hora, arquivo, linha, código e mensagem.

Basicamente você precisa usar essas 3 funções abaixo. Elas capturam todos os tipos de erro e disparam uma `Exception` que será aonde você receba as informações do erro e gera o LOG.

---

<sub>[**(register_shutdown_function)**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.register-shutdown-function.php)</sub>

Registra uma função para ser executada ao final da execução. Sua função `myLog` quando for executada você pode verificar os erros usando `error_get_last()`

```
function myLog()
{
    if( ! is_null( $error = error_get_last() ) )
    {
        // obtendo informações do erro e disparando uma Exception
        extract( $error , EXTR_SKIP );
        new Exception( $message , $type , 0 , $file , $line );
    }
}

register_shutdown_function( 'myLog' );
```

---

<sub>[**(set_exception_handler)**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-exception-handler.php)</sub>

Define uma função do usuário para tratamento de exceções. Geralmente quando uma *exception* é disparada sem captura. Sua variável `$exception` é um objecto e contém as propriedades da classe com os erros, pode dar uma olhada na [DOC Exception](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.extending.php)

```
function myException( $exception )
{
    // mensagem de erro, grave um TXT-LOG com os dados do erro
    echo '<h2>Error</h2><h3>Mensagem:</h3><pre>' . $exception->getMessage() . '</pre>
          <h3>Arquivo:</h3><pre>' . $exception->getLine() . '</pre>
          <h3>Linha:</h3><pre>' . $exception->getLine() . '</pre>
          <h3>Código:</h3><pre>' . $exception->getCode() . '</pre>';
}

set_exception_handler( 'myException' );
```

---

<sub>[**(set_error_handler)**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-error-handler.php)</sub>

Define uma função do usuário para manipular erros. Quando ocorrer um erro, sua função vai identificar e gerar um log ou disparar uma *exception* que será capturado pela sua função acima `myException`.

```
function log_error( $code , $error , $file , $line )
{
    // obtendo informações do erro e disparando uma Exception
    if( error_reporting() === 0 ) return;
    new Exception( $error , $code , 0 , $file , $line );
}

set_error_handler( 'log_error' );
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `set_error_handler` e `register_shutdown_function` para registrar os problemas.

A alguns meses percebi que tinha vários problemas ao trabalhar com mais de um desenvolvedor (um equipe média), haviam vários erros que aconteciam, então fiz um código para isto.

Tente isto (para salvar em arquivos), inclua em todas páginas:

```
<?php
class getErrors
{
    static private $folder = 'data/erros/'; //Configure a pasta
    static private $writeOk = false;

    static public function writeErros($e) {//Erro personalizado
        if (self::$writeOk === true) {
            return NULL;
        }

        self::$writeOk = true;

        $log = fopen(self::$folder . gmdate('d-m-Y_H') . '-GMT.html', 'a+');

        if ($log) {
            $req = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . (
                isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
            );
            fputs($log,
                '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">' .
                '<h1>Erro: ' . $e['message'] . '</h1>' .
                '<p>Página: <a href="http://' . $req . '">http://' . $req . '</a></p>' . 
                (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) === false ? '' : (
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== '' ? ('<p>Referer: <a href="' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '">' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '</a></p>') : ''
                )).
                '<p>Linha: ' . $e['line']  .
                '<p>Arquivo: ' . $e['file']  .
                '<p>$_SERVER:<p><pre>' .
                print_r($_SERVER, true) . '</pre>' .
                '<p>$_GET:<p><pre>' .
                print_r($_GET, true) . '</pre>' .
                '<p>$_POST:<p><pre>' .
                print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>' 
            );
            fclose($log);
        }
    }

    static public function putLastError() {
        $e = error_get_last();
        if (NULL !== $e) {
            self::writeErros($e);
        }
    }

    static public function handleErr($tipo, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $detail) {
        self::writeErros(
            array(
                'message' => $tipo . ': ' . $errstr,
                'line'    => $errline,
                'file'    => $errfile
            )
        );
        return false;
    }
}

set_error_handler(array('getErrors', 'handleErr'), E_ALL|E_STRICT); //Configura a classe para o "handle"
register_shutdown_function(array('getErrors', 'putLastError')); //usar `error_get_last`, geralmente em erros "fatais"
```

> **Nota:** A função `writeErros` captura as variáveis usadas na requisição para você poder ter a ideia de qual a situação que o problema ocorreu

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir uma função como callback se houver erros.

```
set_error_handler()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
function LogErro($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    //o que quiser...
}

set_error_handler("LogErro");
```

A função LogErro() vai ser sempre chamada quando houver erros ou warnings, e você tem os dados do erro nela para poder tratá-los. Veja a explicação das variáveis:

**$errno** Level do erro, em int

**$errstr** Explicação do erro

**$errfile** Arquivo onde ocorreu o erro

**$errfile** Linha onde ocorreu o erro