# Como capturar erros e exceptions para enviar ao BD com PHP?

Tags: php, exceção

Como podemos capturar **todos** os erros e exceptions gerados em tempo de execução no PHP, enviando para o banco de dados para posteriormente fazer uma página de logs organizada?

Atualmente eu redireciono toda requisição para a index.php, tratando as URL de forma amigável com um modelo MVC, então nesse caso seria possível registrar alguma função/callback direto na index.php evitando ter que chamar essa função/callback em todos os arquivos, classes e funções?

Comment: Acredito que o melhor seria enviar para um arquivo .html que você tenha acesso, para servir como um log. Digo isso porque em tese, problemas com o banco de dados também podem ocorrer.

Comment: O que você tentou até agora? Já consegue usar expressões de controle de fluxo como `try..catch`?

Comment: Utilizando o bloco try catch não irá capturar erros de sintaxe ou erros fatais.

Comment: O que vc quere regitrar? Erro tipo 404.., Error SQL (tipo SELCT FROM TAB), Erro do PHP tipo parametros que faltam etc.. o tudo? Porque precisa de "tactica" diferentes. Isso depende tambem do servidor. Vc esta em "local", com um servido dedicado o com um servidor 'mutual'? Ah um ponto MUITO importante para responder: a versao do PHP que vc usa.

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre esta pergunta e [a sua pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34814/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-manipular-erros-do-php-via-c%C3%B3digo)? A resposta mais votada lá responde a esta aqui também. Estou fechando como duplicata enquanto esclaremos isso, ok?

Answer (score 1):

Cuidado: minimo PHP 5.2

```
 <?php


 // ========================
  // Log PHP
 // ========================


 // Chamada quando vai ter Error
 function call_fatal_handler()
 {

     // Déf.
     $err_file = "nao_sei";
     $err_str  = "shutdown";
     $err_no   = E_CORE_ERROR;
     $err_line = 0;

     // Qual e a ultima error?
     $error = error_get_last();

     // Se tem, podems ler dados
     if( $error !== NULL)
     {
         $err_no   = $error["type"];        // Tipo
         $err_file = $error["file"];    // O documento
        $err_line = $error["line"];     // a linha
        $err_str  = $error["message"];  // o mensagem de error

        // Aqui, podemos criar um email, salvar um BDD, ....
        $content = call_format_error( $err_no, $err_str, $err_file, $err_line );
        echo "<br>".$content;
   }
 }

 function call_format_error( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline )
 {

   $trace = print_r( debug_backtrace( false ), true );

   $content = "<b>Error: </b>".$errstr."<br>\n";
   $content .= "<b>Errno: </b>".$errno."<br>\n";
   $content .= "<b>File: </b>".$errfile."<br>\n";
   $content .= "<b>Line: </b>".$errline."<br>\n";
   $content .= "<b>Trace: </b><pre>".$trace."</pre><br>\n";


   return $content;
 }  
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 register_shutdown_function( "call_fatal_handler" );

 echo "Ola";
 //$a = strstr();
 echo "Display".$a;         // $a nao tem definiçao

 ?>
```

Eu esqueci um ponto MUITO importante, se em vez de exibir o resultado, você tenta fazer uma inserção numa BDD, não vai funcionar. Porque como a função é chamada no final do script, neste momento a ligação com o banco de dados é fechado. A solução é fazer outro "sql_open" antes de seu INSERT.

Comment: Se essa função tiver um erro, daí geraria um _loop_ infinito de erros? Por exemplo, a variável `$content` está sendo concatenada sem ter sido declarada, isso não geraria um NOTICE?

Comment: Exato!! Fiz a modificação. Obrigado.