# Tratar erro de compilação em PHP

Tags: php, exceção

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web em PHP com MVC e Smarty. Mas estou tendo o seguinte problema. Meu sistema ao entrar em alguma Exception ele abre um chamado automaticamente já com o erro (insere um valor em uma tabela responsável pelo chamado). O problema começa ai, erro de compilação não entra em nenhum Exception. Por exemplo:

```
    <?php
        $a = 1;
        a
        echo $a;
    ?>
```

Note que tem uma letra solta ali, eu recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in...
```

Já utilizo estas duas funções para pegar os erros do PHP:

```
set_exception_handler('myException');
set_error_handler('myHandler',E_ALL);
```

Tem já implementei classes que herdam a classe `Exception` para tratar os erros. Mais nada resolver este problema.

Comment: Veja se [**essa resposta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34816/13412) ajuda.

Comment: Para referência (em inglês) http://stackoverflow.com/q/13378959/194717

Comment: Muito Obrigado Papa Chalie, me ajudou muito, era isso mesmo que eu precisava.

Comment: @PedroSoares, alguns erros não podem ser capturados por `set_error_handler`, por isso o uso do `shutdown` para capturar o que 'sobra'. Dê uma olhada nessa [*referência*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-error-handler.php#84345).