# Outra opção ao uso do @ no PHP?

Tags: php, session, variáveis, undefined

Não me sinto muito confortável tendo que utilizar o `@` antes de algumas variáveis e sessões quando faço condições, para evitar erro de `Unexpected Index` que acontece quando a variável ou sessão não foi inicializada anteriormente.

Queria saber se não há algum meio de que eu possa setar, num arquivo de topo da minha aplicação por exemplo, uma configuração pro PHP automaticamente fazer isso para todas variáveis e sessões? De repente algum outra solução?

Comment: Na prática estaria tirando algo que não é bom e trocando por algo pior. O certo é corrigir e precaver-se de erros comuns e previsíveis. O inibidor de erros @ é usado para casos bastante específicos como funções que retornam erros inexperados que não podem ser controlados pela configuração de erros.

Comment: @gmsantos Porque minha pergunta foi editada e minha saudação removida? Não lembro de ter lido algo que proíba isso, desculpe se eu estiver errado, mas achei desnecessária sua a interferência...

Comment: @DirtyOldMan esse tipo de saudação é considerada um ruído. Um dos *slogans* do SOPT é [Faça perguntas, obtenha respostas, sem distrações](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Mais detalhes nessa [resposta do meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/52/4751).

Comment: Me desculpe se pareci intrusivo, mas tenho o costume de [fazer esse tipo de edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4751/gmsantos?tab=activity&sort=revisions) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `@` não é uma boa pratica, apesar de poder ser usada, o recomendável para fazer verificações de variáveis é o [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

O [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) diferente do `array_key_exists` (que também pode ser usado conforme o exemplo do Ricardo) suporta verificações multidimensionais e também pode-se verificar mais de uma variável ao mesmo tempo, por exemplo:

- Verificando arrays multidimensionais:

  ```
  <?php
  $test = array('a' => 1);

  var_dump(isset($test['a']['b'])); //Retorna bool (false)
  var_dump(isset($test['a']));      //Retorna bool (true)
  ```
- Verificando mais de uma variável ao mesmo tempo:

  ```
  <?php
  $a = 1;
  var_dump(isset($a)); //Retorna bool (true)
  var_dump(isset($a, $b)); //Retorna bool (false) por que $b não existe
  ```

  ou

  ```
  <?php
  $a = array('test' => 1);
  $b = array('foo'  => 2);

  var_dump(isset($a['test'])); //Retorna bool (true)
  var_dump(isset($a['test'], $b['test'])); //Retorna bool (false) por que $b['test'] não existe
  ```

O [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) também suporta [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) (ou variáveis de uma classe)

### Detalhes sobre o isset:

1. Não é uma função, ele é um construtor
2. Se a variável for `NULL` ou `FALSE` ele irá retornar `false`, como no exemplo:

   ```
   <?php
   $a = NULL;
   var_dump(isset($a)); //Retorna bool (false)
   ```

### empty vs isset

Acaso não for verificar varias variáveis ao mesmo tempo, como no exemplo já citado com [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (`isset($a, $b, $c, $d, $e)`), você pode usar o `empty`, que além de verificar se a "variável existe" ele também verifica se ela é vazia em caso de strings por exemplo. Situações que empty irá retornar `TRUE`:

- `""` (uma string vazia)
- `0` (quando for um numero inteiro igual a zero)
- `"0"` (zero como string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (uma array vazia)
- `var $var;` (Quando uma variavel é declarada em uma classe, mas não tem valor, pois é NULL)

### O problema da pergunta

Como suprimir todas notificações de variáveis não declaradas sem usar o `@`? Neste caso eu recomendaria a usar o `isset` e criar variáveis normais, como por exemplo:

```
$variavelA = empty($_SESSION['varA']) ? NULL : $_SESSION['varA'];
$variavelB = empty($_SESSION['varB']) ? NULL : $_SESSION['varD'];
$variavelC = empty($_SESSION['varC']) ? NULL : $_SESSION['varC'];
$variavelD = empty($_SESSION['varD']) ? NULL : $_SESSION['varD'];
```

Se parecer trabalhoso, você pode usar um loop com `foreach` ou `for`, é um pouco gambiarra admito, mas existem diferentes maneiras de se fazer o processo, está é apenas uma e vai depender de como está o seu código:

```
$keys_in_session = array('a', 'b', 'user', 'ultimaatividade');

foreach ($keys_in_session as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($_SESSION[$v])) {//Acaso a variável não exista na sessão ele cria ela como o valor `NULL` para que você possa usa-la sem ocasionar
        $_SESSION[$v] = NULL;
    }
}
```

### Consideração sobre o uso

Apesar do exemplo com `foreach`, eu pessoalmente recomendo usar apenas o `isset` e o `empty` combinado com `if` ou com operadores de comparação ternários:

```
echo 'Resposta: ', ( empty($_SESSION['message']) ? 'sem resposta' : $_SESSION['message'] );
```

### Ambiente de desenvolvimento vs Ambiente de produção

Como já citado na outra resposta, o uso de `error_reporting` é uma boa pratica para o ambiente de produção e desenvolvimento.

- Ambiente de produção é aquele que se entende no momento que o software já é utilizado para "produzir algo", em outras palavras, quando o site já está no ar.
- Ambiente de desenvolvimento é aquele de quando você está desenvolvendo o software em um local aonde não afete o servidor/site ou seja na sua máquina por exemplo.

Eu pessoalmente sempre uso em ambiente de desenvolvimento todas notificações de erro "ligadas":

```
<?php
//No topo do script
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

No ambiente de produção sempre desligo todos erros:

```
<?php
//No topo do script
error_reporting(0);
```

Porém não é possível determinar todas falhas que possam ocorrer e todas situações, então como saber que erros ocorreram? Para isto temos 3 funções que podemos usar combinados, `error_get_last()`, `set_error_handler` e `register_shutdown_function`, assim você pode gravar os erros em um arquivo `.txt` por exemplo e consultar este arquivo para verificar quando a falha ocorreu, veja um exemplo nesta outra resposta:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34818/3635

> Nota: Não é por que você vai desligar as mensagens de erro que você não deve usar `isset` ou `empty`, procure usar o `E_ALL|E_STRICT` para detectar possíveis falhas do código e depois corrigi-las.

Comment: +1 Essa deveria ser marcada como a resposta correta. Falou sobre `error_reporting` em desenvolvimento e falou sobre `isset` para checar as variáveis. Não é boa prática usar o `@` para evitar os Notices.

Answer (score 5):

> Com esta solução você verifica se a chave do array `session` (ou qualquer outro) existe.

```
if (array_key_exists("login", $_SESSION)) {
    echo "O Usuario esta logado";
}
```

> Com esta solução não será exibido mais `notices` como o `Unexpected Index` (é o que a pergunta pede) porem não resolve do `Unexpected Index`.

Para configurar o php.ini para não exibir as mensagens de notificação você deve deixar da seguinte forma:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Outra forma é colar esta linha no arquivo inicio do arquivo `.php`:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "0");
```

Outra forma é colar esta linha no arquivo inicio do arquivo `.php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // ira reportar todos esceto os `notices`.
```

Comment: Neste caso serão suprimidas as informações de erro, o que não é uma boa prática no ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @RodrigoSpeller Mas foi justamente isto que o autor perguntou.

Comment: Foi adicionado um código que verifica se a chave do $_SESSION existe antes de usa-la inibindo assim o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Segue o arquivo *session_defs.php* para ser incluído no setup do código. Neste arquivo criei a função `session_def`, que define o valor padrão para a variável de sessão caso ela ainda não tenha sido definida.

**Arquivo *session_defs.php***

```
<?php
function session_def($name, $value) {
    // isset: Informa se já variável foi iniciada antes
    if (!isset($_SESSION[$name]))
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value; // Se não foi iniciada,
                                          // inicia com o valor padrão
    return $_SESSION[$name];
}

// Cria a sessão ou resume a sessão atual.
// A partir deste ponto a variável $_SESSION é definida com os valores
// que já foram definidos anteriormente.
session_start();

// Define os valor padrão para as variáveis de sessão que não foram iniciadas
// com session_start.
session_def('item1', 12345);
session_def('item2', true);
session_def('item3', 'string');

?>
```

**Uso**

```
<?php
require_once 'session_defs.php';
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION); 
?>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta é boa, mas não explica o ponto importante, o isset, considere editá-la.

Comment: Editada. Caso tenha restado dúvida sobre o uso da função isset, a documentação do PHP é bem completa [ http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php ].

Answer (score -3):

Normalmente esse erro undefined index é causado por problemas no $_POST ou $_GET.

Você pode executar o comando extract(); no início do código. Assim todas as variáveis já entram de forma automática, sem precisar chamar $_POST ou $_GET.

Basta inserir no início do código:

`extract();`

Esse artigo explica detalhadamente a solução pro erro:

https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/notice-undefined-index-php/