# Excluir simultaneamente imagem do BD e da pasta de destino do servidor

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando excluir simultaneamente uma determinada imagem que esta no campo "logo" de uma tabela que tem vários outros campos, e da pasta onde esta armazenada que se chama "upload", porém somente consigo excluir toda linha da tabela referente ao campo "logo", e mesmo assim não exclui da pasta "upload".

O objetivo é para que quando o usuário decida alterar a imagem, não fique as imagens antigas sobrecarregando o servidor, já que elas não estão sendo mais usadas.

Segue abaixo o código que já tenho:

```
   <?php
   include 'conexao.php';
   $pasta = 'upload/';
   if (isset($_POST['deletar'])){
   $check = @$_POST['apagar'];
   foreach($check as $logo){
   $delcheck = mysql_query("DELETE FROM topo WHERE logo = '$logo'") or die (mysql_error());
   unlink($pasta.$delcheck['logo']);
   if ($delcheck >= '1'){
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Deletado com sucesso!");
   window.location.href = "listar.php";
   </script>';
   }else{
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Erro, tente novamente!");
   window.location.href = "listar.php";
   </script>';
   }}}
   ?>

   <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br />
   <?php
   include 'conexao.php';
   $seleciona = "SELECT * FROM topo";
   $queryum = mysql_query($seleciona);
   while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($queryum)){
   $logo = $list['logo'];
   ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $logo; ?>" readonly><?php echo $logo; ?><br />
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   <input type="submit" name="deletar" value="Excluir"><br />
   </form>
```

Comment: Prezado Amigo: Seu script esta na mesma raiz, pois quando dá um unlink na pasta/arquivo upload/NOME DO ARQUIVO DE IMAGEM. Tente colocar `error_reporting(E_ALL);` no inicio do script para ver se algum erro aparece para voce. Na verdade esta função nem sempre funciona, depende da instalação do PHP. Pois é possivel sumprimir toda e qualquer saida de erros. Nao da nenhum erro ? Seu PHP esta com o modo de erro habilitado?

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a minha resposta lhe ajudou? Se não, informe poderia teve alguma duvida no uso dela.

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma série de problemas no teu script:

1. Você deve levar em consideração é o uso de caminhos relativos, se a pasta `./upload/` não estiver no mesmo diretório que a pasta do teu script, então ele nunca irá conseguir encontrar o arquivo. Recomendo que sempre use caminhos absolutos, para isto crie um arquivo "global" (incluído no começo em todos scripts) para sempre apontar pra pasta correta usando uma variável, por exemplo:

   - global.php

     ```
     <?php
     define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', strtr(dirname(__FILE__), '\\', '/') . '/');
     ```

   `ABSOLUTE_PATH` irá exibir algo como `c:/wamp/projeto/` ou  `/etc/www/projeto/` ou `/home/user/htdocs/`. Se a pasta upload no seu servidor estiver localizada em `/home/user/htdocs/upload/`, então bastará usar o unlink assim (apenas um exemplo):

   ```
    unlink(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'upload/arquivo.jpg');
   ```
2. O `unlink` pode retornar `true` se conseguiu excluir ou `false` caso contrario. Você deve usar isto ao seu favor combinado com `if`, o que você não fez.
3. Você está `foreach`, da a entender que são vários logos que você necessita deletar, mas o teu script usa `window.location.href`, o redirecionamento deveria somente ocorrer após o loop.
4. Você criou duas variáveis `$_POST['deletar']` e `$_POST['apagar']`, você deveria ter usado apenas o `isset`, leia esta resposta que fiz em outra pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63550/3635
5. Você usou `if ($delcheck >= '1'){`, mas note que `mysql_query` não retorna numeros ou strings e sim valores "booleanos".
6. Funções que começam com o nome `mysql_` estão em desuso e logo serão descontinuadas, ou seja assim que o seu servidor (ou servidor dos teus clientes) atualizarem pra versões mais recentes do PHP os teus script irão parar de funcionar e irão emitir várias sequencias de erros semelhantes a este:

   > Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in arquivo.php on line 1

   Leia sobre isto em nesta outras respostas:

   - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/3635
   - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66489/3635
7. Você está deletando os logotipos pelo endereço da imagem, quando o preferível seria usar o id da tabela do banco.
8. **Recomendação:** Prefira usar [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)