# Frase "E-mail enviado com sucesso" na mesma pagina do Formulário. Como configurar?

Tags: php

Tenho visto formulários com o aviso de "E-mail enviado com sucesso" na mesma pagina do formulário após seu envio.
o meu formulario funcionava bem quando fazia o arquivo php separado e no formulario o chamava: action="enviar.php".

Mas acho mais interessante o usuário nao ser telas brancas nem telas adicionais sem precisão. Entao tentei direcionar o meu action para mesma pagina: action="#". Mas dai tive todas as variaveis como ondefinidas. ja tentei resolver e nao consegui, Onde esta o erro? Imagino que deve ser algo simples.

O codigo é um sistema de comentario funcional, mas busquei adaptações para transferir para mesma pagina a frase, dai entao deixou de funcionar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Classificdos</title>
</head>
<style>
    div#container{
        width: 50%;
        text-align: justify;
        background: blue;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family: helvetica;
        padding: 3%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>NOTICIA DO DIA</h1>

        <hr/>


        <h3>Deixe seu comentário</h3>

        <?php 
        //error_reporting(0);
    if(isset($_POST['comentar'])){
        $nome =         $_POST['nome'];
        $email =        $_POST['email'];
        $site =         $_POST['site'];
        $comentario =   $_POST['comentario'];
        $identificacao= $_POST['identificacao'];
        $moderacao =    $_POST['moderar'];
    }
        if(isset($_FILES['avatar']))
   {
      date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão

      $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['avatar']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
      $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
      $dir = 'uploads/'; //Diretório para uploads

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo
  }


        $headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        $headers = "From: $email";
        $para    = "teste@servidor.com";
            $mensagem = "De: $nome";
            $mensagem .= "E-mail: $email";
            $mensagem .= "Site: $site";
            $mensagem .= "Comentario: $comentario";



        $envia = mail($para, "Comentário Efetuado no site", $mensagem, $headers);


        $insere = ("INSERT INTO comentarios (id, nome, email, site, comentario, identificacao, moderacao, avatar ) VALUES ('NULL', '$nome', '$email', '$site', '$comentario', '$identificacao', '$moderacao', '$new_name')"); //new_name e o novo nome da $avatar defidido por horas.

        $insereBanco = mysql_query($insere);

            echo "<p><strong>$nome</strong>, seu comentário foi efetuado com sucesso e aguarda liberação. Obrigado!";
            echo "<p><a href='Sistema_comentarios.php'>Voltar</a></p>";

        ?>

        <form id="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Preencha os Campos Abaixo:</legend>

                    <label for="nome">NOME: </label>
                        <input type="text" required id="nome" name="nome">
                            <div class="clear"></div>

                    <label for="email">E-MAIL: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                            <div class="clear"></div>

                    <label for="site">SITE (Opcional): </label>
                        <input type="text" id="site" name="site">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label for="comentario">Deixe seu Comentário</label><br/>
                        <textarea name="comentario" id="comentario" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>

                    <label id="escolher_foto" for="foto">Escolher uma Foto</label>
                     <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" required="">

                    <input type="submit" value="Comentar"><br/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="identificacao" value="1"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="moderar" value="nao"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu já editei duas pergunta suas e coloquei o aviso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/115563/3 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/115424/2, tenha mais atenção,  O stack snippet é obviamente usado para executar javascript, html e css, ou seja front-end, não tem porque usar stacksnippet para colocar php, c++, java, c#, isso nunca vai funcionar. Use a marcação normal se for só pra exibir códigos.

Comment: Desculpa. Quando voce fala o stack snippet é nas opções da pergunta o botão "Trecho" e a marcação normal que voce fala para eu usar é o botão "Amostra de codigo"? porque eu eu quero fazer da forma certa.

Comment: sim o "trecho" é ele mesmo, realmente a tradução tá esquisita, entenda assim o "trecho" deve ser usado quando o código puder ser EXECUTADO, como uma execução de um "javascript" ou um efeito html+css, ou uma tag HTML5 que não está funcionando em determinado navegador. PHP, C#, C/C++ não podem ser executados no stacksnippets. No caso você só quer mostrar o código, sendo assim use o "amostra de código"...

Comment: ... Desculpe não é querendo lhe criticar, longe disso, mas no botão "trecho" aparece assim `trecho javascript/html/css ctrl+m`, isso não é claro o suficiente? Não é por mal que pergunto, é que estou tentando propor aos ADMs uma mudança no layout pois muitos se confundem, mesmo parecendo óbvio, gostaria de entender o que te levou a confundir pra sugerir uma solução no meta.stackexchange.

Comment: Eu entendo é tranquilo. Vou te responder...Coloquei porque os arquivos que enviei contem html, tanto que tem a tag html5. Neste caso olhei a toda a barra de botoes e nao vi nada sobre PHP, pensei para nao errar mais feio e por em css ou javascript, era o obvio para mim que a unica opcao restante era o html. Mas foi por falta de informação na barra. Não associei meu codigo completo como uma amostra apenas.

Comment: mas é ae que está o problema é HTML que possa ser reproduzido, se a ideia é só mostrar a o HTML e não reproduzir um problema "do HTML" então não tem porque usar o stacksnippet, acho que o problema na verdade é que poucos entendem o que é o stacksnippet ou jsfiddle, recomendo que leia: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ e http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: Chegou a ler a minhas resposta, sobre o uso do `isset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa encapsular seu código PHP que trata de *receber os parâmetros POST e salvar no banco e enviar o email* dentro do seguinte IF:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     // seu código vai aqui
}
```

Dessa forma, se seu usuário apenas entrar na sua página pela URL, o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` vai ser igual a `"GET"`, você não vai realizar nenhuma operação no PHP e apenas exibir a página de comentários para ele, o HTML.

E quando seu usuário submeter o formulário de comentários, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` vai ser igual a `"POST"` e então sim seu código PHP de *envio de email + save na DB + mensagem de que o comentário foi salvo* vai ser executado. Segue como seu PHP deve ficar dentro do arquivo:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //error_reporting(0);
    if(isset($_POST['comentar'])){
        $nome =         $_POST['nome'];
        $email =        $_POST['email'];
        $site =         $_POST['site'];
        $comentario =   $_POST['comentario'];
        $identificacao= $_POST['identificacao'];
        $moderacao =    $_POST['moderar'];
    }

    if(isset($_FILES['avatar'])) {
        date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão

        $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['avatar']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
        $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
        $dir = 'uploads/'; //Diretório para uploads

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo
    }

    $headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    $headers = "From: $email";
    $para    = "teste@servidor.com";
    $mensagem = "De: $nome";
    $mensagem .= "E-mail: $email";
    $mensagem .= "Site: $site";
    $mensagem .= "Comentario: $comentario";

    $envia = mail($para, "Comentário Efetuado no site", $mensagem, $headers);

    $insere = ("INSERT INTO comentarios (id, nome, email, site, comentario, identificacao, moderacao, avatar ) VALUES ('NULL', '$nome', '$email', '$site', '$comentario', '$identificacao', '$moderacao', '$new_name')"); //new_name e o novo nome da $avatar defidido por horas.

    $insereBanco = mysql_query($insere);

    echo "<p><strong>$nome</strong>, seu comentário foi efetuado com sucesso e aguarda liberação. Obrigado!";
    echo "<p><a href='Sistema_comentarios.php'>Voltar</a></p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Taylan, o `` é para código, para salientar texto, você pode usar o negrito ou italico.

Comment: @DiegoF Blz, nem tinha pensado sobre. Vlws pelo fix.

Comment: @tayllan perfeito, era exatamente isto, e sua resposta me apontou outra pequena falha que resultou no funcionamento do codigo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

O uso de `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {` não é garantia, podem haver falhas no script se usar ele ou apenas ele, como de alguma maneira o formulário html falhar ou faltar algum campo e ainda sim poderá ser enviado, mas faltando "inputs", recomendo que use `isset` ou `empty`, como eu expliquei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63550/3635

Um maneira de usar o `isset`

```
<?php
//Inicia o IF
if (isset($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['site'], $_POST['comentario'], $_POST['identificacao'], $_POST['moderar'], $_POST['comentar']))
{

    $nome =         $_POST['nome'];
    $email =        $_POST['email'];
    $site =         $_POST['site'];
    $comentario =   $_POST['comentario'];
    $identificacao= $_POST['identificacao'];
    $moderacao =    $_POST['moderar'];

    if(isset($_FILES['avatar']))
    {
        date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão

        $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['avatar']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
        $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
        $dir = 'uploads/'; //Diretório para uploads

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo
    }


        $headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        $headers = "From: $email";
        $para    = "teste@servidor.com";
            $mensagem = "De: $nome";
            $mensagem .= "E-mail: $email";
            $mensagem .= "Site: $site";
            $mensagem .= "Comentario: $comentario";



        $envia = mail($para, "Comentário Efetuado no site", $mensagem, $headers);


        $insere = ("INSERT INTO comentarios (id, nome, email, site, comentario, identificacao, moderacao, avatar ) VALUES ('NULL', '$nome', '$email', '$site', '$comentario', '$identificacao', '$moderacao', '$new_name')"); //new_name e o novo nome da $avatar defidido por horas.

        $insereBanco = mysql_query($insere);

            echo "<p><strong>$nome</strong>, seu comentário foi efetuado com sucesso e aguarda liberação. Obrigado!";
            echo "<p><a href='Sistema_comentarios.php'>Voltar</a></p>";

} //Termina o IF
?>
```

Recomendo que leia a documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php