# Qual é a diferença na verificação de um array com isset e array_key_exists?

Tags: php, array

No PHP muitas vezes, temos mais de  uma forma de fazer uma mesma operação. Um exemplo básico é na verificação da existência de um determinado índice em um `array`: podemos usar `array_keys_exists`.

Exemplo:

```
$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];

var_dump(isset($arr['a'])); // bool(true)

var_dump(array_key_exists($arr, 'a')); //bool(true)
```

Considerando que os resultados são os mesmos, gostaria de saber:

- Existe alguma diferença entre `isset` e `array_keys_ exists` quando a verificação da existência do índice?
- Existe diferença quanto à performance?
- Quando deveria usar um ou outro?

Comment: Isso ajuda em algo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63550/3635 ?

Comment: No [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php#example-5087) diz: isset() não retorna TRUE para valores de chave que correspondam a um valor NULL, enquanto que array_key_exists() faz isto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu dei uma breve explicação nesta resposta [Outra opção ao uso do @ no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63550/3635), mas vou tentar definir melhor aqui a diferença conforme as perguntas feitas aqui.

Respondendo primeiro:

> Existe alguma diferença entre `isset` e `array_keys_ exists` quando a verificação da existência do índice?

> Quando deveria usar um ou outro?

### Usando array_key_exists

O `array_key_exists` apenas verificar se a chave existe em uma array retornando um valor `bool`, deve-se usar somente quando necessita saber se uma chave especifica existe em um array, mesmo que ela tenha o valor `null` ela ainda retornará `true` se a chave existir, exemplo:

```
$foo = array( 'baz' => 0 );

var_dump(array_key_exists('baz', $foo));
```

### Usando isset

O `isset` não é uma função, mas o importante é entender como ela funciona, a primeira diferença é que `isset` suporta múltiplas checagens assim:

```
isset($foo['baz'], $foo['bar'], $_POST['foo']);
```

E claro que o resultado varia conforme você adiciona elementos.

Outra diferença é que ele faz a checagem não só de `arrays`, mas de variáveis normais, por exemplo se fizer isto em uma variavel não definida ele não emite Warning:

```
<?php isset($foo); ?>
```

Mas isto emite a mensagem *Undefined variable*:

```
<?php echo $foo; ?>
```

Isto porque ao tentar usar `$variável` mesmo que não exista ela passa "tecnicamente a existir" e o valor é `NULL` pro PHP.

Outra característica é que pro `isset` retorna `false` caso a variável ou item de um array for `null`, mesmo que exista:

```
$foo = NULL;

var_dump($foo);

$test = array( 'foo' => NULL );

var_dump($test['foo']);
```

> Existe diferença quanto à performance?

Isto varia muito, alguns dizem que por que o `isset` não é uma função mas sim um "construtor" é provável que ele seja mais rápido. Na maioria dos casos isto pode estar certo, até mesmo se considerar versões mais antigas do PHP, mas dependendo do tipo de verificação é provável que a diferença seja tão insignificante que nem vale a pena comparar (é apenas uma "micro otimização" no máximo), mas o que digo é que pra maioria dos casos de checagem, `isset` vai ser melhor, por exemplo como citei a possibilidade de verificar múltiplos itens ou variáveis.

> <sup>**Nota:**</sup> pra remover um item de um array use o `unset`, nele é possível remover vários itens ou variáveis `unset($foo1, $foo2, $foo3);`

### Usando empty

Outra função (ou construtor) que pode ser interessante usar é o `empty`, ele verifica o tipo de valor, ele irá retornar `false` pra quando o valor do item ou variável for:

- `""` (uma string vazia)
- `0` (quando for um numero inteiro igual a zero)
- `"0"` (zero como string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (uma array vazia)
- `public $var;` (Quando uma variável é declarada em uma classe, mas não tem valor, pois é NULL)

Answer (score 7):

Como nosso amigo [Papa Charlie](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13412/papa-charlie) falou, o retorno varia de acordo com os valores do array. Esse código vai te mostrar um retorno diferente dos dois métodos citados.

```
<?php

$arr1 = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
$arr2 = ['a' => null, 'b'=>2];

var_dump(isset($arr1['a'])); // true
var_dump(array_key_exists('a', $arr1)); // true

var_dump(isset($arr2['a'])); // false
var_dump(array_key_exists('a', $arr2)); // true

?>
```

O isset te ajuda a verificar a existência de uma chave com valor **nulo**.

**Respondendo suas perguntas...**

1. Existe alguma diferença entre isset e array_keys_ exists quando a verificação da existência do índice?
   **R: <strike>Para esta verificação, não.</strike>Se o array tiver chave e valor preenchidos, não tem diferença. Caso o valor seja nulo, existe diferença sim.**
2. Existe diferença quanto à performance?
   **R: Sim. isset() é mais rápido, apesar de não ser exatamente igual à outra função.**
3. Quando deveria usar um ou outro?
   **R: array_key_exists() verifica se a chave (neste caso, "a") existe. Mas não verifica se o valor é nulo ou não. Já o isset(), faz essa verificação e retorna false (como no exemplo do código postado acima).**

Comment: A resposta à primeira pergunta está errada: Se existe diferente entre as duas quanto a verificação da existência. Pois no caso de  `['a' => null, 'b' => null]` os índices existem, mas estão nulos.

Comment: Wallace Maxters, obrigado! Não atentei p/ isso. **resposta corrigida**

Comment: Obrigado pela maturidade de receber a crítica/correção. Não é todo mundo que aceita ;)

Answer (score 5):

`array_key_exists()` vai lhe devolver se a chave existe ou não no array, independente do valor que ela possui. `isset()` vai lhe devolver `bool(true)` apenas se a chave existir no array **E** o valor dela for diferente de `null`.

Outra diferença é que se você passar uma variável não definida para o `isset()` ele apenas devolve `bool(false)`, já o `array_key_exists()` printa um **PHP WARNING** na tela e devolve `NULL`:

```
var_dump(isset($array['a'])); // bool(false)
var_dump(array_key_exists('a', $array)); // lança um "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable" e imprime "NULL"

$array = ['a' => null, 'b' => 2];

var_dump(isset($array['a'])); // bool(false)
var_dump(array_key_exists('a', $array)); // bool(true)

var_dump(isset($array['b'])); // bool(true)
var_dump(array_key_exists('b', $array)); // bool(true)
```

Logo, utilize `array_key_exists()` quando você quiser saber se a chave existe ou não no array (independente do valor) e você **tem certeza que o array ao menos existe**, e `isset()` quando você quiser ter certeza que a chave existe **E** que ela é diferente de `null`.

Veja o código funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/CEWa3n).

Comment: "utilize array_key_exists() quando você quiser saber se a chave existe ou não no array", mas sabe que o ao menos o array existe.

Comment: @guilhermelautert corrigido, valew.