# Tratativa para index indefinido no array

Tags: php, array

Caros desenvolvedores experientes e aprendizes da arte de codar.

Acredito que seja comum em algum sistema você ter que verificar o próximo item de um `array`. Por exemplo neste caso estou verificando se o próximo é igual ao item anterior:

```
$item_anterior = "";
$array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$ainda_nao_foi = true;

for($i=0;$i<$array.lenght();$i++){   

   if($ainda_nao_foi){   
     echo "<p>O Site do Stack overflow é demais! .$array[$i].</p>";
     $item_anterior = $array[$i];
     $ainda_nao_foi = false;
   }
   //próximo
   $j = $i + 1;

   if($item_anterior != array[$j]){
        $ainda_nao_foi = true;
   }
}
```

Mesmo usando a função **isset()** para verificar se está setado, isso não ajudaria, pois as vezes meu array pode retornar com valor vazio.

O problema é que neste `if`:

```
if($item_anterior != array[$j]){
   $ainda_nao_foi = true;
}
```

O `PHP` gera um `warning` avisando que o index não está definido. Existe um função que verifica se tem esse índice no `array`? para não estourar o erro?

Comment: Eu entendi que você quer verificar se o próximo item é igual ao atual, mas qual é a saída esperada? Pode ser que tenha alternativas melhores para resolver isso.

Comment: Pode ser que dê esta mensagem após $i atingir o último valor possível e o $j queira ir mais adiante, já que seu valor é $j=$i+1. O maior índice é 10, no seu caso, mas $j quer ir até 10+1, que não existe.

Comment: Se apenas precisa de comparar um elemento com o seguinte porque não simplificar e alterar o `for` para `< length - 1` ? Assim nem precisa do anterior, basta comparar diretamente com o próximo, porque sabe que é sempre valido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para verifica se a chave existe mesmo que o valor seja `null` use a função [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) no lugar do [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) pode juntar essa verificação no segundo if.

```
$item_anterior = "";
$array = [0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, '', null, null];
$ainda_nao_foi = true;

foreach($array as $k => $v){

    if($ainda_nao_foi){
        echo "<p>O Site do Stack overflow é demais! .$array[$k].</p>";
        $item_anterior = $array[$k];
        $ainda_nao_foi = false;
    }

    $j = $k + 1;

    if(array_key_exists($j, $array) && $item_anterior != $array[$j]){
        $ainda_nao_foi = true;
    }
}
```

Um exemplo mais simples da diferenção das funções:

```
$arr = array(1, null, '' , 'teste');

var_dump(isset($arr[1])); //false
var_dump(array_key_exists(1, $arr)); //true
```

**[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/hwI9U8)**

**Relacionada:**

[Qual é a diferença na verificação de um array com isset e array_key_exists?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117474/91)

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria o inverso, ao invés de verificar o próximo, verificaria o anterior:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $array.lenght(); $i++){   
   if(($i == 0) || ($array[$i - 1] != $array[$i])) 
     echo "<p>O Site do Stack overflow é demais! .$array[$i].</p>";
}
```

Mas se você quiser manter nesse formato, poderia adicionar um `if`:

```
$item_anterior = "";
$array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$ainda_nao_foi = true;

for($i=0;$i<$array.lenght();$i++){   

   if($ainda_nao_foi){   
     echo "<p>O Site do Stack overflow é demais! .$array[$i].</p>";
     $item_anterior = $array[$i];
     $ainda_nao_foi = false;
   }
   //próximo
   $j = $i + 1;

   if(($j < $array.lenght()) && ($item_anterior != array[$j])){
        $ainda_nao_foi = true;
   }
}
```