# Unir arrays por chaves iguais, mas separando valores

Tags: php

#### Cenário (exemplo):

Tenho 2 `Arrays`, **X e Y** (*criados dinamicamente, individuais*):

```
$arX = Array('AAA' => 173.696, 'BBB' => 72.436, 'CCC' => 142.692);
$arY = Array('AAA' => 127, 'DDD' => 72.333);
```

---

#### Objetivo:

O que gostaria, é de **uni-los pela chave, mas, separar os valores**.

**Exemplo** do resultado esperado:

```
Array
    (
        [AAA] => Array
        (
            [X] => 173.696,
            [Y] => 127
        )
        [BBB] => Array
        (
            [X] => 72.436
        )
        [CCC] => Array
        (
            [X] => 142.692
        )
        [DDD] => Array
        (
            [Y] => 72.333
        )
    )
```

---

#### Dúvidas:

- Existe uma função nativa para isso?
- Como poderia obter o resultado?

Comment: Pergunta da hora +1. Ótimo desafio :p

Comment: Cara, tá osso pensar na pressa que eu estou. Depois dou uma resposta melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um unico `foreach` com `array_key_exists` já resolveria o problema, pois desta forma só vai iterar uma vez, exemplo com uma função (não precisa ser uma função se vai usar somente uma vez):

```
<?php

function mesclar(array $arrX, array $arrY)
{
    //Cria uma nova array
    $z = array();

    //Pega as chaves de ambas arrays
    $chaves = array_merge( array_keys($arrX), array_keys($arrY) );

    foreach ($chaves as $chave)
    {
        // A performance do `=== false` é minima ou nenhuma na maioria dos casos, mas se o array for gigante mesmo talvez isto torne o script razoavelmente mais performatico
        if (isset($z[$chave]) === false) {
            $z[$chave] = array();
        }

        //Copia o valor do primeiro array para X
        if (array_key_exists($chave, $arrX))
        {
            $z[$chave]['X'] = $arrX[ $chave ];
        }

        //Copia o valor do primeiro array para Y
        if (array_key_exists($chave, $arrY))
        {
            $z[$chave]['Y'] = $arrY[ $chave ];
        }
    }

    return $z;
}

$arX = array('AAA' => 173.696, 'BBB' => 72.436, 'CCC' => 142.692);
$arY = array('AAA' => 127, 'DDD' => 72.333);

$novaArray = mesclar($arX, $arY);

print_r( $novaArray );
```

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/3loYc9

Comment: Não está trazendo o "DDD". 

Comment: @rbz tem toda razão :/ vou revisar

Comment: @rbz revisado https://ideone.com/3loYc9

Comment: Não sei se muda algo, mas assim `if (array_key_exists($chave, $z))` funciona também. Melhoraria o "problema" que você disse "A performance do `=== false`......" ?

Comment: @rbz não tem porque checar nada no `$z`, ela é uma array totalmente nova que é criada depois de passado os valores. O `=== false` só terá diferença em arrays gigantes, geralmente mesmo em array gigantes o ganho é pouco, mas eu criei o script sem saber qual cenário vc vai precisar, ou seja um script que funciona bem para os grandes e pequenos processos.

Comment: Desculpa minha confusão... mas o `isset` não está checando se `$z` tem aquela chave, da mesma forma que o `array_key_exists`?

Comment: @rbz `isset` e `array_keys_exists` são semelhante, mas não identicos, é como eu disse no começo, eu não tenho ideia de quantos valores teu array vai ter e nem muito menos se os valores serão sempre numeros, se ocorrer de aparecer um NULL no meio dos valores o `isset` iria ignorar a chave especifica, por isso eu fiz o script contra falhas em todos cenários possiveis (pois não tenho ideia da sua aplicação real) - Veja esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117504/3635

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `array_walk` para realizar o que necessita.

O ponto central, é referenciar no `callback` qual é o novo array que você irá criar (`$newArray`) e, como terceiro parâmetro de `array_walk`, o prefíxo da chave (que pode ser `X`, `Y` ou qualquer outra chave que quiser, caso houverem mais arrays).

```
$arX = Array('AAA' => 173.696, 'BBB' => 72.436, 'CCC' => 142.692);
$arY = Array('AAA' => 127, 'DDD' => 72.333);
$newArray = [];

$callback = function($value, $key , $prefix) use (&$newArray)
{
    //valida se a chave já existe no array
    if (!array_key_exists($key , $newArray))
    {
        $newArray[$key] = [];
    }

    // Adiciona o novo array ao já existente, utilizando o prefixo enviado via parâmetro.
    $newArray[$key] += [$prefix => $value];
};

//Cada array será processado individualmente e adicionado em $newArray
//que é referenciado no callback.
array_walk($arX , $callback , "X");
array_walk($arY , $callback , "Y");
```

Resultado:

```
array(4) {
  ["AAA"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["X"]=>
    float(173.696)
    ["Y"]=>
    int(127)
  }
  ["BBB"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["X"]=>
    float(72.436)
  }
  ["CCC"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["X"]=>
    float(142.692)
  }
  ["DDD"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Y"]=>
    float(72.333)
  }
}
```

Código em funcionamento: https://3v4l.org/Xmlv4

Comment: `isset` pode falhar acaso o valor seja null.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, mas, ai depende da necessidade do autor da pergunta. Alterei para array_key_exists

Answer (score 1):

Eu tinha tentado dar uma resposta mais elaborada, usando funções sofisticadas de array, mas nada foi mais fácil que usar o próprio `foreach`.

Veja:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($arX as $key => $value)
{
    $result[$key]['X'] = $value;
}

foreach ($arY as $key => $value)
{
    $result[$key]['Y'] = $value;
}


var_dump($result);
```

Resultado:

```
[
 "AAA" => [
   "X" => 173.696,
   "Y" => 127,
 ],
 "BBB" => [
   "X" => 72.436,
 ],
 "CCC" => [
   "X" => 142.692,
 ],
 "DDD" => [
   "Y" => 72.333,
 ],
]
```

Se ainda quiser insistir no uso de funções para fazer isso, pode combinar o poder do `array_merge_recursive` com `array_map`.

veja:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive(
    array_map(function ($x) { return ['X' => $x]; }, $arX),
    array_map(function ($y) { return ['Y' => $y]; }, $arY)
);
```

Numa terceira opção, você poderia usar o operador + junto com `array_keys` para iterar com todas as `keys` dos seu array.

Veja:

```
$result = [];

foreach (array_keys($arX + $arY) as $key) {

    if (isset($arX[$key]))
        $result[$key]['X'] = $arX[$key];

    if (isset($arY[$key]))
        $result[$key]['Y'] = $arY[$key];
}
```

Comment: Gostei dessa última opção! Ficou bem limpa. Convém trocar o `isset` para `array_key_exists`?

Comment: @rbz depende, o único problema do `isset` nesse caso é que, se a chave existir, porém for `NULL`, ele retorna `FALSE`, mas acredito que pro seu caso não faça diferença.