# Sintaxe Isset e foreach

Tags: php

Olá!
Minha dúvida é, posso trabalhar com mais de duas variáveis no isset e foreach?

tenho esse código:

```
if(isset($_POST["produto"]) && $_POST["qtd"]){

    echo "Ítens escolhidos:<BR>";
      
    $table  = '<table>';
    $table .= '<thead>';
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td>Produto</td>';
    $table .= '<td>Qtd</td>';
    $table .= '<td>Valor</td>';                                     
    $table .= '</tr>';
    $table .= '</thead>';
    $table .= '<tbody>';
    
    foreach(array_combine($_POST["produto"], $_POST["qtd"]) as $numero =>     $quantidade){

        $table .= '<tr>';                   
        $table .= "<td>{$numero}</td>";
        $table .= "<td>{$quantidade}</td>";
        // $table .= "<td>{$valor}</td>";                               
        $table .= '</tr>';
    
    }
          
    $table .= '</tbody>';
    $table .= '</table>';
                                
    echo $table;
    
}else {

    echo "Você não preencheu o formulário ainda!<br>";
}
```

Quero inserir o campo valor no isset e no foreach, como fica a sintaxe?

Comment: Pode sim Clayton, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117504/3635

Answer (score 0):

eu faria assim:

```
if(isset($_POST["produto"],$_POST["valor"]) && $_POST["qtd"] > 0){

echo "Ítens escolhidos:<BR>";
  
$table  = '<table>';
$table .= '<thead>';
$table .= '<tr>';
$table .= '<td>Produto</td>';
$table .= '<td>Qtd</td>';
$table .= '<td>Valor</td>';                                     
$table .= '</tr>';
$table .= '</thead>';
$table .= '<tbody>';

$num_produtos = count($_POST['produto']);

for($x=0;$x<$num_produtos;$x++){
    $numero = $_POST['produto'][$x];
    $quantidade = $_POST['qtd'][$x];
    $valor = $_POST['valor'][$x];

    $table .= '<tr>';                   
    $table .= "<td>{$numero}</td>";
    $table .= "<td>{$quantidade}</td>";
    $table .= "<td>{$valor}</td>";                               
    $table .= '</tr>';

}
      
$table .= '</tbody>';
$table .= '</table>';
                            
echo $table;
```

}else {

```
echo "Você não preencheu o formulário ainda!<br>";
```

}

Apenas cuidado para declarar as variaveis enviadas como array:

```
<form>
   <input name=produto[]>
   <input name=qnt[]>
   <input name=valor[]>
</form>
```

Comment: Interessante, só que deu o seguinte erro aqui:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' in 
for(x=0;x<$num_produtos;$x++){

Comment: foi mal faltou o $ antes da variável

Comment: acabei de aprender que o isset aceita sim multiplas variáveis, vou melhorar a resposta