# Tratar erros de páginas web com PHP

Tags: php, servidor

Olá!
 Há a possibilidade de quando houver um erro 404, por exemplo, meu servidor enviar um email me notificando do ocorrido através do php?

Comment: Teu servidor usa Apache?

Comment: Sim. Na verdade estou fazendo esses testes através do wamp na minha máquina.

Comment: Praticamente todos os sites na internet são acessados por bots que vasculham vulnerabilidades e acabam caindo na página 404. Como resultado poderá receber centenas, senão milhares de emails. Uma dica é apenas gerar logs e então 1 vez ao dia, num agendamento automatizado, seria enviado apenas 1 email com o relatório dos logs do dia. Enfim, é apenas um conselho. Siga o que for conveniente e adequado para o seu caso.

Comment: Porque não faz teste o Xampp é facil de uso e melhor praticar de desenvolver PHP. Se esta com problema web é pode ser conflito a porta, no windows 10 pro, tente `NET STOP HTTP` é tente reiniciar aplicativo web server. flw

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver usando apache você pode criar um arquivo .htaccess na raiz com este conteudo:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /home/user/public_html/enviar_erro.php
```

> Supondo que o a sua pasta "raiz" seja `public_html`

O arquivo enviar_erro.php:

```
<?php
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: eu@seudominio.com\r\n"; // remetente

$mensagem = 'Url não encontrada: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . PHP_EOL;

if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $mensagem .= 'Referencia: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . PHP_EOL;
}

mail("destinatario@algum-email.com", 'Erro HTTP', $mensagem, $headers);

echo '404 error';
```

E se quiser pegar os erros de script você pode usar como nesta outra resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34818/3635, crie um arquivo chamado `detectar_erro.php`:

```
<?php
class getErrors
{
    //Seu email
    static private $enviarPara = 'destinatario@algum-email.com';

    //Destinatário email
    static private $remetente = 'destinatario@algum-email.com';

    static private $writeOk = false;

    //Erro personalizado
    static public function writeErros($e)
    {
        if (self::$writeOk === true) {
            return NULL;
        }

        self::$writeOk = true;

        $req = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . (
            isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] :
                                                    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        );

        $mensagem = 'Erro: ' . $e['message'] . PHP_EOL .
                    'Página: http://' . $req . PHP_EOL .
                    (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? '' :
                        ('Referer: http://' . $req . PHP_EOL)
                    ) .
                    'Linha: ' . $e['line'] . PHP_EOL .
                    'Arquivo: ' . $e['file' PHP_EOL;

        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: " . self::$remetente . "\r\n"; // remetente

        mail(self::$email, 'Erro no PHP', $mensagem, $headers);
    }

    static public function putLastError()
    {
        $e = error_get_last();

        if (NULL !== $e) {
            self::writeErros($e);
        }
    }

    static public function handleErr($tipo, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $detail)
    {
        self::writeErros(
            array(
                'message' => $tipo . ': ' . $errstr,
                'line'    => $errline,
                'file'    => $errfile
            )
        );

        return false;
    }
}

//Configura a classe para o "handle"
set_error_handler(array('getErrors', 'handleErr'), E_ALL|E_STRICT);

//usar `error_get_last`, geralmente em erros "fatais"
register_shutdown_function(array('getErrors', 'putLastError'));
```

E inclua no topo em todos arquivos principais assim:

```
<?php
require_once 'detectar_erro.php';
```