# Em ambiente de produção os erros devem ser desabilitados?

Tags: php, ux

Vi que erros gerados em ambiente de produção resultam em grandes problemas, principalmente quando se tem uma aplicação relacionada à dinheiro e/ou senhas, mas também devido a privacidade das informações.

- Em ambiente de produção, tudo já hospedado, funcionando com pessoas reais, os erros gerados devem ser desabilitados? Através do comando:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );
?>
```

Uma vez que podem ser gerados problemas, com senhas de banco, de outros websites e assim infinitamente, desabilitar os erros é a melhor alternativa?

---

Como dito nos comentário, exatamente

- Como eu poderia não exibir a mensagem de erro e sim criar *logs* de erros, então redirecionar o usuário para a página anterior, informando "Ocorreu um erro"?

Comment: Em produção o melhor é não exibir nenhuma mensage de erro ou informação sobre o sistema/tecnologia/framework/plataforma etc para não fornecer nenhum detalhe para um possível atacante.

Comment: Acho que não se pode mostrar informação possivelmente perigosa, mas isso não impede que você tenha logs bem escondidos e descritivos sobre erros :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você pergunta sobre: É necessário usar o ini_set('display_errors', 0);?
O error_reporting(0); já não é o suficiente? enquanto que eu pergunto se: Uma vez que podem ser gerados problemas, com senhas de banco, de outros websites e assim infinitamente, desabilitar os erros é a melhor alternativa?

Comment: Você pergunta sobre funcionalidade, enquanto eu pergunto sobre teoria, não é a mesma pergunta duplicada

Comment: Você marcou a pergunta como duplicada, então fui ver o que estava duplicado da outra pergunta, e lá você pergunta sobre: É necessário usar o ini_set('display_errors', 0);? O error_reporting(0); já não é o suficiente? enquanto que eu pergunto se: Uma vez que podem ser gerados problemas, com senhas de banco, de outros websites e assim infinitamente, desabilitar os erros é a melhor alternativa?

Comment: Tudo bem, mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: Eu somente estava dizendo que acho que a pergunta não parece duplicada uma vez que Você pergunta sobre funcionalidade do ini_set e error reporting, enquanto eu pergunto sobre teoria: "Uma vez que podem ser gerados problemas, com senhas de banco, de outros websites e assim infinitamente, desabilitar os erros é a melhor alternativa?" e posteriormente eu fiz um edit incrementando: a pergunta "exatamente como eu poderia não exibir a mensagem de erro e sim criar logs de erros, então redirecionar o usuário para a página anterior, informando "Ocorreu um erro"?", não parece a mesma pergunta duplicada

Comment: Talvez sua outra pergunta pode até ficar como uma "relacionada", mas ao meu ver, não como duplicada

Comment: @SauldaSilvaRolim veja a edição http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195941/3635 eu também reabri a pergunta.

Comment: Quando o programador está criando o sistema em servidor Local, é necessário que a os erros estejam habilitados, para que com isto o mesmo possa corrigi-lo, por outro lado, quando temos um sistema já pronto e hospedado, é a melhor opção ocultar todas as mensagens de erros, pois se um usuário mal intencionado pegar este erro, poderá utilizar o mesmo contra o próprio sistema, causando assim uma grande dor de cabeça.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como apresentar as exceções não tratadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243816/como-apresentar-as-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-n%C3%A3o-tratadas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nunca use `error_reporting(0);`, isto afeta mais do que exibir os erros, ele afeta os *logs* salvos, o que não é uma boa ideia, use apenas o:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Isto já irá evitar dos erros serem exibidos ao usuário e o máximo que ele irá obter é o "500 Internal Error Server'

Uma configuração ideal para o `error_reporting` seria:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Isto fará com que todos os erros sejam salvos no *log* (se estiver habilitado o tal *log*), exceto as notificações, erros do tipo *strict*, erros de uso e erros de funções, classes ou funcionalidades descontinuadas.

**Mais detalhes nesta resposta**: [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106563/3635)

Para desenvolvimento recomendo habilitar tudo mesmo, afinal é desenvolvimento:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

> Note que nas versões modernas do PHP apenas `E_ALL` é o suficiente, o uso de `E_ALL|E_STRICT` foi mais por retro-compatibilidade.

Em produção no php.ini você pode configurar os *logs* de erro setando assim:

```
error_log = /home/user/php/logs.txt
```

Não há problema algum em fazer isto em ambientes de homologação e desenvolvimento, já que existem página que podem ser requisitadas via Ajax e você pode não conseguir notar o erro quando estiver desenvolvendo.

Note também que em alguns servidores compartilhados geralmente não tem como alterar o `error_log =`, mas geralmente ele já esta habilitado e usando o `echo ini_get('error_log');` (não vá exibir para o usuário `:)`) você pode pegar o local aonde foi salvo e talvez por SSH ou SFTP baixar o *log* diário gerado.

Um outro exemplo de como captar os *logs* como citei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34818/3635, seria usando `set_error_handler` combinado com `register_shutdown_function`, você poderia usar isto para enviar um erro para um e-mail, ou algo assim.

De qualquer forma eu diria que o ideal é corrigir o máximo de erros possíveis e testar bem o sistema antes de enviá-lo para produção e se houver algum erro que não foi possível detectar o *log* deverá informar apenas a ti.

---

### Como exibir erros de forma amigável

> ... como eu poderia não exibir a mensagem de erro e sim criar *logs* de erros, então redirecionar o usuário para a página anterior, informando "Ocorreu um erro"?

No geral entre exibir ou não é o menor dos problemas ao meu ver, a questão é o sistema falha e ocasionar uma série de **efeitos colateiras** em cascata, por exemplo gerar registros inválido/incompletos no banco, como disse o ideal é tratar tudo que for possível, por exemplo usando *mysql* com *innodb* (myisam não suporta isto) você tem o *rollback*:

```php
if (!mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT ... xyz...')) {
    die('Erro ao inserir xyz');
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE... status...')) {
    die('Erro ao atualizar status');
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE... chat...')) {
    die('Erro ao atualizar chat');
}
```

Supondo que a ultima *query* falhe, mas ela é importante, você teria atualizações em *status* e em *xyz* que não deveria haver, pois o sistema falhou, agora se usar:

```php
/*Desativa o autocommit*/
mysqli_autocommit($link, false);

if (!mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT ... xyz...')) {
    die('Erro ao inserir xyz');
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE... status...')) {
    mysqli_rollback($link); //Desfaz
    die('Erro ao atualizar status');
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE... chat...')) {
    mysqli_rollback($link); //Desfaz
    die('Erro ao atualizar chat');
}

mysqli_commit($link);
```

Ele só fara o *commit* se tiver passado por todos `ifs`, claro que isso é um exemplo bem simplório, outra situação é que as pessoas costumam sempre pegar dados de `$_GET` e `$_POST` sem checar, fazendo simplesmente isto:

```php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Quando poderiam fazer isto (é apenas um exemplo):

```php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if (!validaNome($nome)) { //Função "teórica"
     die('Dados do formulário vazio');
}

if (!$email) {
     die('Dados do formulário vazio');
}
```

Estes seriam alguns exemplos, o `die` é opcional, no caso eu acho complicado o uso dele quando depende do layout, você poderia agrupar os erros e envia-los no final, mas isto é questão de experiencia e de como o teu sistema foi projetado. Agora sobre erros no script que não tenham haver diretamente com "lógica" ou dados perdidos, ou seja os erros FATAIS e de PARSE, como eu disse deveriam ser coisas que você deve checar sempre no desenvolvimento, mas claro que entendo que isto pode volta e meia ocorrer, no caso você poderia usar o `set_error_handler` e o `register_shutdown_function` combinados para exibir uma mensagem fixa no topo ou se usar `ob_start` poderia gerar uma página de erro sem mais nada (note que `ob_start` pode elevar o consumo do servidor, o que pessoalmente eu não acho uma boa ideia, eu só o citei como um exemplo, existe outras maneira de fazer isto), por exemplo:

- crie um global.php

  ```php
  <?php
  ob_start(); //Inicia o buffer

  function handleErrors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $details = null) {
      static $log; //Variavel static para detectar erros repetidos

      if (isset($loggers) === false) {
           $log = array();
      }

      $localizacao = $errfile . ':' . $errline;

      if (in_array($localizacao, $log)) {
           return true;
      }

      $localizacao[] = $localizacao; //Salva o erro para evitar ser eviado mais de de uma vez

      $msg = 'Erro ' . $errstr .
             ' no arquivo: ' . $errfile .
             ' na linha: ' . $errline;

      error_log($msg, 1, 'email@servidor.com');

      ob_end_clean(); //Limpa o buffer

      require 'erroamigavel.php';

      return true; //Não executa o "handler interno" do PHP
  }

  set_error_handler('handleErrors', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);

  register_shutdown_function(function () {
       $error = error_get_last();
       $type = $error['type'];

       if (!in_array($type, array(E_NOTICE, E_STRICT, E_DEPRECATED))) {
           handleErrors($type, $error['message'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
           );
       }
  });
  ```
- Inclua este global.php em todos arquivos no começo assim:

  ```php
  <?php
  require_once 'global.php';
  ```

  > Note que se o arquivo que você incluiu tiver um erro de PARSE o global.php provavelmente não irá funcionar
- E depois crie um arquivo chamado `erroamigavel.php` com o conteúdo que desejar para exibir ao usuário, por exemplo:

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Erro</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Ouve um erro na página</h1>
      <p>Os administradores já foram notificados e estão trabalhando para corrigir</p>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  > note que é tudo exemplo, não é algo que será copiar e colar, eu mesmo não sou "fã" de `ob_start()` pelo motivo que já citei, só o uso se necessário mesmo é possível fazer de outras maneiras, mas depende muito de como seu sistema foi criado, no meu *framework* pessoal por exemplo eu consigo fazer algo assim sem precisar de `ob_start()`.

Comment: @SauldaSilvaRolim Otimo, só estou em duvida que função é esta chamada msglog, seria uma função de um framework?

Comment: Não foi usuário que saiu não! eu não consigo ver esse voto quando visualizo o positivos e negativos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você disse que recebeu um voto negativo, mas, ele não aparece aqui na sua pontuação!

Comment: Mas, para ele desfazer isso a sua pergunta tem que ser editada ou estou enganado @GuilhermeNascimento ?

Comment: @Stormwind deve ser, no painel consta: `desfazer o voto o favor`, foi viagem da minha mente maluca :P

Comment: Essa dos `commits` foi ótima! Muito bom mesmo!

Answer (score 3):

E recomendado que seja desabilitado, nem um erro deve ser exposto ao usuário, pois falhar no seu sistema podem acabar sendo demostrada, os erros devem ser tratado na aplicação e mostrado sempre telas amigáveis ao usuário.

Obs: isso é apenas uma recomendação e uma boa prática, ficando ao seu critério o que realmente será feito no seu servidor de produção.

Log é essencial para que você possa capturar todos os erros e pode tratar posteriormente.

Answer (score -3):

sim deve ser desabilitado, pois uma pessoa mal intencionada pode se aproveitar de uma falha e conseguir acesso ao bancos de dados e assim pegar informações de seus clientes e os erros que aparecem nada mais são de variáveis que não estão sendo utilizada, mas também podem aparecer vulnerabilidades no sistema que pode resultar em uma perda grande financeira e entre outros motivos devem ser desabilitados sim no ambiente de produção após estar tudo funcionando corretamente.

Answer (score -3):

Respondendo a pergunta do **EDIT**, você deveria usar blocos try/catch e exceptions, estou meio enferrujado no php mas se não me engano não é tão dificil e já ouvi dizer que no php7 ficou mais fácil ainda, portanto o correto é sempre "tratar o erro" e para tratar o erro voce deve capturá-lo, logo temos que o mais correto é: prever quais pontos podem dar erro e criar exceptions e blocos try/catch para tratar esses erros, obviamente nem todos os erros serão identificados logo de primeira, mas o ideal é tentar atingir o maior numero de cenários. Ex: 
No cadastro de um usuário o campo nome não pode ser vazio.
Você criar uma exception por exemplo NomeNaoVazioException e dispara ela caso o nome seja vazio: nome == vazio? trhow NomeNaoVazioException e na hora de setar ou na hora de salvar voce faz um try/catch

```
try
{
    //tenta salvar o usuario
}
catch(NomeNaoVazioException $e)
{
    //trata o erro enviando o ator para a tela anterior com mensagem de erro
}
```

Comment: Acho essa opção horrível. Usar `try/catch` especificamente não quer dizer que você tratou os erros. Em casos de variáveis que não tenham índices, um simples `if` com `isset` resolveria. Mas o problema vai mais além de simplesmente "reforçar as verificações". Toda aplicação tem bug, então é melhor sempre deixar a exibição de erros desabilitada.

Comment: Só pra ver se entendi, você está desestimulando o uso do `try/catch` ? E ao invés disso está estimulando o uso de `if/else` ? Obviamente que apenas try/catch Nao garante que foram eliminados erros porém dizer que acha horrível usar esse artifício e meio pesado, se tu não usa, como então trata fluxos de excessão nas tuas aplicações?

Comment: Não​ disse que desaprovo, mas usar isso pra tudo é fazer mal uso do recurso. Existem várias formas de tratar o erro (no PHP inclusive são inúmeras ocasiões diferentes para poder tratar). Eu acho horrível vender a ideia de que try\catch resolva tudo em PHP, porque isso não é verdade.