# Como apresentar as exceções não tratadas?

Tags: exceção, ux, usabilidade

Toda aplicação falha, é fato. Em uma aplicação desktop Windows, quando uma exceção que não foi tratada estoura, o seguinte explode na tela do usuário, fechando o programa:

[image]

Não é uma [tela azul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death), entretanto inconveniente, não explicativo e genérico. O irônico é que um retorno nunca é dado para o usuário (ao menos nunca me retornaram com uma solução, como diz a mensagem).

Pessoalmente, no macOS a experiência para o usuário é ainda pior! Uma mensagem e vários dados técnicos que o utilizador final não faz ideia do que seja:

[image]

E isso não é específico de aplicações desktop. Sempre que algo inesperado ocorre, independente da arquitetura da solução, é comum ler mensagens como:

- um erro fatal ocorreu;
- um erro inesperado ocorreu;
- erro desconhecido;
- ops, algo deu errado;
- um erro ocorreu e não será possível continuar, <del>troque o programador.</del>

Os erros não tratados e irrecuperáveis devem ser apresentados? Deveriam conter dados técnicos e códigos de erro? Deve ter uma opção para entrar em contato com o(s) desenvolvedor(es) da aplicação? Que pontos devem ser observados ao informar esse tipo de erro?

<sub>Estou atrás de soluções que estejam fundamentadas nas heurísticas da usabilidade e da experiência do usuário (UX). Respostas com caráter totalmente opinativo ou sem fundamentos serão negativadas; ao invés de postar como resposta, podemos discutir nos comentários ou no *chat*.</sub>

Comment: Essa pergunta se encaixaria melhor na tag [tag:erro] (que não existe mais)

Comment: "Troque o programador" -> hahaha!

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 5):

Não sou especialista em UX. Pro meu gosto, não falar muito para o usuário comum me parece o ideal na maioria dos casos. Para usuário técnico pode ser útil dar informações que ajudem ele fazer alguma coisa.

O mecanismo de exceção é usado para duas coisas: indicar erros de programação; e indicar situação anormal encontrada. Bem, também usam para outras coisas, mas o foco aqui não é discutir esse abuso.

Erro de programação não tem porque ser informado em detalhes para o usuário. Tem que *logar* e/ou mandar para o desenvolvedor. Minha experiência é que raramente consegue ser muito específico em erros de programação para o usuário final (e é onde para o programador precisa de tudo isso que a exceção costuma gerar, em outros tipos de erro não precisa de nada daquele monstrengo gerado em cada exceção).

Erros circunstanciais nunca deveriam quebrar a aplicação, deveria tentar se recuperar, ainda que exija alguma intervenção do usuário. Não tratar esse tipo de exceção passa ser erro de programação.

Geralmente erros de programação deveriam ser tratados em um único local. Não deve ficar tentando tratar erros de programação por toda base de código. Não tem como ficar tentando se recuperar, tratar de forma específica ou dar muita informação ao usuário.

Talvez fosse o caso de ser mais transparente e dizer que o erro foi do programador.

É possível pedir *feedback* para o usuário do que ele estava fazendo além de enviar para o desenvolvedor o máximo que a aplicação puder coletar sobre o problema. Parece que no MacOS está fazendo isto, mas não de forma óbvia que incentive o usuário fazê-lo.

Há quem goste de copiar a tela para *logar* junto, há até quem consiga enviar um *dump* detalhado do que ocorreu. Em geral criar o *dump* é muito caro para a aplicação, por isso tem aplicação que consegue ligar só em momento específico.

Há aplicações que não se deixam quebrar, começam tudo de novo. Se fizer certo pode ser interessante. Se a aplicação ficar com coisas penduradas antes de recomeçar pode causar problemas. Eu prefiro deixar quebrar mesmo.

Mas o pouco que aprendi é que tem que testar com os usuários o que funciona melhor. Os detalhes farão muita diferença e aqui não terá uma resposta adequada com eles. No geral é pensar no que é útil para o usuário, não para você. Pense antes de fazer, não vá no automático.

Em perguntas de UX prefiro mais ouvir do que falar :) Espero melhores respostas.