# Como modificar todas as mensagens de erro do PHP7?

Tags: php

Estou finalizando meu projeto e em breve vou colocar o site na minha hospedagem. Não quero que meu usuário veja uma mensagem de "Warning" ou qualquer outra. No lugar delas quero que apareça:
"Ocorreu um erro, Entre em contato conosco. Se possível, mande um print do problema."

Comment: Essa pergunta te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34814/5878

Comment: Não é possível mexer nas configurações do PHP7 para modificar o texto dos erros? php.ini ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Acredito que não e isso não parece ser viável.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar aqui então, vlw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível definir um *exception handler* para manipular todas exceções ou erros não tratados com [`set_exception_handler`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-exception-handler.php), basta passar qualquer *callable* pra ele:

```
set_exception_handler(function ($e) {
    echo 'Ocorreu um erro, Entre em contato conosco. Se possível, mande um print do problema.';
    echo 'Mensagem do erro: ' . $e->getMessage();
});
```