# Não Consigo Capturar Erros Nativos do PHP?

Tags: php

Estou tentando tratar erros nativos do `PHP` para caso passe algo despercebido, o erro seja tratado e mostre de uma mensagem de maneira mais amigável ao cliente, porem mesmo usando o `Throwable` no `try catch`, ele simplesmente estoura o erro e não cai no `catch`.

Já tentei com `Exception`, `ErrorException Throable` mas nenhum funciona, e não consigo entender o que esta errado.

Exemplo de erro:

```
function logar($objectFactoryGeral,$toGeral){
    try {
        $SBLogin = $objectFactoryGeral->SBC_Usuario()->SBLogin();            
        $email = 59/0;//.$_REQUEST['email'];
        //$senha = $_REQUEST['senha'];            
        $toLogin = $toGeral->ITOLogin($email,$senha);        
        $SBLogin->logar($toLogin);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        return  RetornaExcecaoCOJS($e->getMessage());
    }        
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [É possível manipular erros do PHP via código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34814/3774)

Comment: Pelo que eu entendo deveria, através do try catch.

Answer (score -1):

Eu sempre crio para toda aplicação que faço um **error handler** para tratar os erros

```
function errorHandler($mensagem, 0, $level, $arquivo, $linha)//Transforma erros em Exceptions
{
   if(error_reporting() !== 0) //Para manter o operador @ funcionando
   {
      throw new ErrorException($mensagem, 0, $level, $arquivo, $linha)
   }
}

function exceptionHandler($exception)
{
   //O que você quiser fazer com o erro, exemplo:
   echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
   echo "<p>Mensagem:'". $exception->getMessage() ."</p>";
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler');//Transforma erros em exceções 
set_exception_handler('exceptionHandler');//Função que trata as exceções (e erros)
```

Somente o que não for pego por um catch sera tratado pelo **exceptionHandler**